# If $ab\equiv ac\pmod n$ and $a \not\equiv 0\pmod n$, then $b\equiv c\pmod n$ is true whenever $(a, n) =1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $ab$ is congruent to $ac \pmod n$ and $a$ is not congruent to $0 \pmod n$, then $b$ is congruent to $c \pmod n$.

This was a homework problem and I was asked to show that this is false for some set of integers. I came up with $a = 4, b = 8, c = 5,$ and $n = 6$. Then $4*8 -4*5 = 12$, which is divisible by $6$ and $4$ is not divisible by $6$.

The last part is false with this set of numbers $8 -5 =3$ and is not divisible by $6$.

Now I need to prove that the statement is true if $(a, n) = 1$.

*I will post my thoughts/attempts very soon.

Comment: Just to clarify, I would now appreciate a full solution as this problem will not be submitted for grading, but was assigned as homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ab ≡ ac(mod n) and a≢0(mod n), then b≡c(mod n) is true whenever (a, n)=1.

(a, n)= 1 implies that there exist integers u, v such that au + nv =1. Then au ≡ 1 (mod n).

Take ab ≡ ac (mod n) and multiply by u. abu ≡ acu (mod n), which implies b ≡ c (mod n) since 
au ≡ 1 (mod n).

Any criticism will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ (n,a)=1,\ n\,|\,a(b\!-\!c)\:\Rightarrow\:n\,|\,b\!-\!c\:$ by Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: `\rm` is back? ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $(a,n)=1$, there are integers $k,m$ such that $ka+mn=1$, and it follows that $ak\equiv 1\pmod n$. Thus, $k$ is $a^{-1}$ modulo $n$.

Comment: Really appreciate your comment, but can you please remind me why $ak\equiv 1\pmod n$ ?

Comment: Because $ka + mn = 1 \pmod n$

Comment: @grayQuant: Since $ka+mn=1$, $1-ka=mn$, i.e., $n\mid 1-ka$; by definition, then, $1\equiv ka\pmod n$.